# Android URLConnection returns ASCII decimals?

Tags: android, decimal, ascii, urlconnection

I'm building an Android app that uses URLConnection to grab the content of a webpage, but for some reason it turns symbols like the actual Apostrophe (') into it's ASCII decimal value (`&#39;`)

Example: `Let's go to the party` becomes `Let&#39;s go to the party`.

I already tried setting the InputStream charset to ASCII, but that didn't help.

Code:

```
            String bodyHtml;

        URL url = new URL(webPage);
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
        InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, "ASCII");

        int numCharsRead;
        char[] charArray = new char[1024];

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((numCharsRead = isr.read(charArray)) > 0) {
            sb.append(charArray, 0, numCharsRead);
        }

        /*StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while ((numCharsRead = isr.read(charArray)) > 0) {
            sb.append(charArray, 0, numCharsRead);
        }*/

        bodyHtml = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Try volley by Google :-)

Comment: ' new InputStreamReader(is, "ASCII");'. ???? ASCII ???? Remove that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to convert the received string to html and back to string. Html.fromHtml(value) will convert the received value to html. calling .toString() will return you the string (without any html tag )

```
// import this package
import android.text.Html;
```

after receiving the content from the url.. you can convert that content to readable form..

```
String value ="Let&#39;s go to the party";

String formattedValue =   Html.fromHtml(value).toString().trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [URLDecoder.decode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html)

```
bodyHtml = URLDecoder.decode(bodyHtml);
```

Comment: Seems deprecated. I tried java.net.URLDecoder.decode(sb.toString(), "UTF-8"); but that didn't sort the problem